# How to implement a notification tray like in google+

Tags: android, notifications

How can I implement a notification tray like in google+, which slides in from the right side?

I can't find any good manual.

Thanks

Comment: I do not quite understand what you want to implement. On my phone nothing slides from the right in the G+ application. Maybe a screenshot with explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DrawerLayout, and add one tag:- layout_gravity="end" or "right".

EDIT: here is the link: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html